# Regular Expression for Finding Everything Between Two Slashes

Tags: regex, url, search, find, slash

I'm trying to use a regular expression to find everything that falls between 2 slashes in a list of URLs.

When I use

```
/.*?/
```

with a URL like

> /blog/article/test

...the expression will find /blog/, but will not find /article/. I'm guessing this is because the first result includes that slash, so the second ignores it. I know this is probably a simple fix, but I'm stumped.

Comment: What language/tool are you using and do you expect to get `/blog/article/` as match?

Comment: I have just been using the grep function of Notepad++. I'd like to get /blog/ and /article/ as results.

Answer (score 0):

see [**HERE**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `lookaround assertions`.

try this:

```
(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\/)
```

apart from getting past preventing *character consumption*, u'll need to use the `global` flag  so that the `regexp` doesnt stop at just the *first match* in the input-string.

```
/(your regex)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your desired result just by avoiding '?' in your regex.

My try has shown these results

```
> echo /blog/article/test | sed -e 's;\(/.*?\);\1;'
 /blog/article/test
> echo /blog/article/test | sed -e 's;\(/.*/\).*;\1;'
 /blog/article/
```

Hope this helps.